Insert a blank row based on change in value of an array
I have  a Master list from which i have created "views" based on array formulas
I have used the code below  and a ref column to add blank lines ok .
The issue im having is that the data is wiping half the responses off as it somehow needs to reset the array after the blank line each time
Sub AddBlankRows2gg()

    Const cCol As Variant = "AI"
    Const cFirstR As Long = 1

    Dim vnt As Variant
    Dim LastR As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    vnt = Split(cCol, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(vnt)

        LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, vnt(i)).End(xlUp).Row

        iRow = cFirstR
        Do
            If Cells(iRow, vnt(i)) <> "" And Cells(iRow + 1, vnt(i)) <> "" Then
                If Cells(iRow, vnt(i)) <> Cells(iRow + 1, vnt(i)) Then
                    Cells(iRow + 1, vnt(i)).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                    'Cells(iRow + 1, vnt(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = i + 3
                    LastR = LastR + 1
                End If
            End If
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop Until iRow > LastR
    Next

End Sub

The result im after is for a blank row to be added based on changes to value in column E whilst all responses generating and totaling in cell I3 Correctly

Add Blank Rows


Looping backward is the more natural way, and you don't have to increment twice.
It is not clear to me what issues you are encountering. If they don't get resolved with this code, please share more information with practical examples.

Sub AddBlankRows()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2 ' > 0; 2 assumes one row of headers
    Const CHECK_COLUMNS As String = "A" ' 'DELIMITER'-separated
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","
    Const COLOR_OFFSET As Long = 3
    Const MATCH_CASE As Boolean = False
    
    ' Reference the workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Return the column headings (strings) in a String array.
    Dim CheckColumns() As String:
    CheckColumns = Split(CHECK_COLUMNS, DELIMITER)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim ccell As Range, LastRow As Long, cRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim cCol As String, cString As String, pString As String
    Dim AreBothStringsNotBlank As Boolean, AreStringsDifferent As Boolean
    
    ' For each column heading, loop backwards from the last row to the row
    ' below the first and for each row determine whether the current
    ' and previous cells are not blank and whether they are different.
    ' Only then insert a blank row between them.
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(CheckColumns)
        cCol = CheckColumns(i)
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow > FIRST_ROW Then ' there is data below the first row
            cRow = LastRow
            Do
                AreBothStringsNotBlank = False ' reset
                Set ccell = ws.Cells(cRow, cCol)
                cString = CStr(ccell.Value)
                If Len(cString) > 0 Then
                    pString = CStr(ccell.Offset(-1).Value)
                    If Len(pString) > 0 Then
                        AreBothStringsNotBlank = True
                    End If
                End If
                If AreBothStringsNotBlank Then
                    AreStringsDifferent = False ' reset
                    If StrComp(cString, pString, MATCH_CASE) <> 0 Then
                        AreStringsDifferent = True
                    End If
                End If
                If AreStringsDifferent Then
                    With ccell
                        .EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                        ' Note that the inserted row is above 'ccell'
                        ' and has shifted 'ccell' down
                        ' while the previous cell remaines as is.
                        .Offset(-1).Interior.ColorIndex = i + COLOR_OFFSET
                    End With
                End If
                cRow = cRow - 1 ' decrement!
            Loop While cRow > FIRST_ROW ' or Loop Until cRow = FIRST_ROW
        'Else ' no data
        End If
    Next i

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Blank rows inserted.", vbInformation

End Sub


That worked perfectly adding the spaces          the issue i have is the total of the column is halved as the array that puts it into this sheet orders the results       this is the code putting the data into each row                                                                                  =IF(ROWS(C$10:C10)<=$AB$6,INDEX(INDIRECT(ADSM!D$5),SMALL(IF(TT=$AB$2,ROW(TT)-ROW(ADSM!$D$7)+1),ROWS(C$10:C10))),"")

would it be easier if i added the spreadsheet ?

You could post a link here in the comments so I can download it or the file to my email found on my profile page. If the latter, let me know that you have sent it.
